# Alan Turing posthumously pardoned by British government

Tags: discussion

This might not be appropriate for meta (certainly not main) but it seems like something which many in the community would be interested in discussing. If the community thinks this should be closed, feel free to vote for closure.

Alan Turing, famous mathematician and code-breaker in the Second World War, was this morning officially pardoned by the Queen, 59 years after this death, for his 1952 conviction for gross indecency (partaking in homosexual activities). Many agree that this conviction, and the accompanying sentence, contributed to his assumed suicide in 1954 at the age of 42. You can read the pardon [here](http://cryptome.org/2013/12/turing-pardon.pdf). Turing received an official apology from the government in 2009 from Gordon Brown (then prime minister), but a pardon holds somewhat more weight and is an important milestone. A good write up of this saga can be read [here](http://aperiodical.com/2013/12/alan-turing-royal-pardon/). It's unfortunate that this didn't happen last year in the [centenary of Turing's birth](http://www.mathcomp.leeds.ac.uk/turing2012/).

As Turing was such an influential mathematician, and contributed so greatly to the allied war-effort during WWII, and has recently become somewhat of a figurehead for gay-rights advocates (especially in the science and mathematics community), I feel it would be appropriate to express my support at seeing such a pardon be given (especially at this festive time of year). It would have certainly been more ideal if the pardon were extended to the other 50,000-100,000 convicted of the same 'crime', but perhaps it is better that this story has a famous face attached to it.

I personally hope these events encourage even more people from the LGBT community to consider starting a career in mathematics. I also hope these events encourage those already in the mathematics community to be more tolerant and welcoming to everyone that has a passion for mathematics.

Comment: [Email announcement](https://plus.google.com/104979143639484917985/posts/dhzuU4tN3o5) by [Barry Cooper](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6sbc/).

Comment: While I agree with what you're saying, the meta.math.stackexchange.com site is not for metamathematics; it is **only** for discussing the website math.stackexchange.com.